# How can I get fastapi hot reload to work inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a fastapi application running inside a docker container using docker compose. I'm using this for development so I would like the docker container to automatically rebuild upon changes to the files. How can I do that? I tried adding '--reload' to the CMD inside the Dockerfile and matching workdir and local file structure but I couldn't get it to work.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN mkdir /server
WORKDIR /server

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/server
```

file structure

```
├── backend
│   └── main.py
|   └── Dockerfile
|   └── requirements.txt
├── docker-compose.yml
```

Comment: Your host system probably already has Python preinstalled (at least if it's a Linux or MacOS host); can you use a pure-Python virtual environment here instead?  What benefit are you hoping to get from running this in an isolation system like Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze I chose Docker because one of the required dependencies (grpcio) doesn't work on M1 Mac. I'm still new to this. Can I get this to work using a virtual environment?

Answer (score 3):

Hello you've probably figure out already. In case you didn't just add this command in your docker-compose.yml

```
 command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 --reload
```

So, the file you've share should be like this:

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 --reload
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/server
```

the "command" entry will override the CMD in your Dockerfile and the "--reload" will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the **watch** instruction and the **docker compose watch** command.

It will automatically update and preview your running Compose services as you edit and save your code. https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/

My *docker-compose.yaml*:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  server:
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./server
          target: /opt/app
        - action: rebuild
          path: ./server/requirements.txt
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The *Dockerfile* from which I build the FastAPI server image in the *docker-compose.yaml* above:

```
FROM python:3.12.2-bullseye

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /opt/app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /opt/app/requirements.txt

COPY . /opt/app

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT [ "uvicorn", "src.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--reload"]
```

*ENTRYPOINT* and *--reload* flag are important here. You could probably also use the entrypoint instruction directly in your *docker-compose.yaml*

To run it, you simply type in **docker compose watch**. If you'd like to have both logs from the Compose services and syncing, you can run **docker compose watch** and **docker compose up** in two terminals.